# Run maven command with the DOT not working for passing TestNG suite as parameters

Tags: java, spring, maven, testng

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!-- pass testng.xml files as argument from command line -->
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How to pass this variable now with mvn command?
Tried:

```
mvn clean install test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng-suite.xml 
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng-suite.xml
```

Always getting the error, seems like connected to . (dot) symbol not treated as expected:

> Unknown lifecycle phase ".xml". You must specify a valid lifecycle
> phase or a goal in the format : or...
>
> Unknown lifecycle phase ".suiteXmlFiles=testng-suite.xml". You must
> specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal

Same problem have when passing any properties - treats dot as some lifecycle phase...

Answer (score 0):

Put the variables in single or double quotes like...

```
mvn '-DsuiteXmlFile=testng-suite.xml' clean install test
mvn '-Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng-suite.xml' clean test
```

Answer (score -1):

do it like this

```
mvn -DsuiteXmlFile=testng-suite.xml  clean install test 
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng-suite.xml clean test
```

Comment: Unfortunately same problem (( It also colores dot symbol differently, like it's some command [link](https://ibb.co/pKG8bfr)

Comment: works fine for me in both variants Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)